Issue with aggregate SUM function to add up quantities at the selected level in Oracle analytical view
I am trying to aggregate SUM function to add up quantities at the selected level in Oracle analytical view:
CREATE OR REPLACE ANALYTIC VIEW inventory_av
USING INVENTORY_FACT
DIMENSION BY (
    inventory_attribute_dim KEY (LOCATION_ID)
    REFERENCES (LOCATION_ID)
    HIERARCHIES (inventory_hier DEFAULT)
)
MEASURES (
   QUANTITY FACT QUANTITY ,
   QUANTITY_SUM as (SUM(QUANTITY))
);

but I am getting this error:

Error report -
ORA-00934: group function is not allowed here
00934. 00000 -  "group function is not allowed here"
*Cause:
*Action:


Is it not "QUANTITY_SUM QUANTITY AGGREGATE BY SUM" or "QUANTITY_SUM as (SUM(QUANTITY) OVER(inventory_hier))" ?
